# Can't get paypal sandbox to work on old SOAP api (using java legacy SDK)

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working on some old code which uses the PayPal JAVA legacy SDK to connect to PayPal SOAP endpoints. The production environment works fine with minor issues but the sandbox doesn't seem to work. I have obtained fresh credentials from PayPal and it seems the error I am getting is a 400 (Bad Request).

The following is the API url being used in the sandbox.

https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/

I was wondering whether the API url is deprecated. Any help on this matter is appreciated.

Comment: In theory it still works, but that is an unusual error to be getting. You should log the full text of the SOAP request and the response if you want more help

Comment: I am using a very old PayPal SDK where I can't find any documentation on. Most of the stuff is inside a **paypal_base.jar** and it works fine in production (in most cases).